# Bring index info to the groupby selection in PYthon Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe called 'grouped':

[image]

I am using the following code to bring the max/min for each column:

```
mm = grouped.agg(['max', 'min'])
mm
```

That brings me:

[image]

I know I can use '.T' to invert rows and columns but I still need to add which 'Day' this result happened.

The desired result I am looking for is:

[image]

can someone give me a hand?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: Copy data like text with 4 spaces before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html), [`DataFrame.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html), then rename index and transpose:

```
mm = (grouped.agg(['max','idxmax', 'min', 'idxmin'])
             .rename({'idxmax': 'DateMax', 'idxmin': 'DateMin'})
             .T
             .astype({'DateMin':'int', 'DateMax':'int'}))
```

Comment: The DateMax/DateMin column created displays the days with a '.0' such as '12.0'. Is there a way to make it just '12'?